# Handel http requests between 2 servers

Tags: apache, dns, round-robin, dyndns, namecheap

i have a website hosted in 2 different servers , i want to avoid losing traffic when one server of them go down , is there any way to balance the redirect between these 2 servers in the register side (namecheap) , so if the primary server went down the request will be redirected automatically to the other server.

Thank you

Comment: Round robin DNS won't help, you need a load balancer, which itself would regularly check each server and only send traffic to ones that are up. A reverse proxy could function like that too.

Comment: Load balancer in register side ?

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/load-balancing/ is one option.